# Does the size of the seed (in bits) for a PRNG make any difference?

Tags: python-3.x, random

I have looked through StackExchange sites, Google, Wikipedia, and all the other usual sources and have been unable to find a good answer to my question.

"Does the size in bits matter when seeding a pseudo-random number generator?

I understand that, in many or most cases, time is used as the seed value but the explanations give for why this is so all deal with it being a useful method of getting a constantly changing seed value. Size does not seem to be an issue.

I am starting to dig into some crypto related issues and this has piqued my curiosity. As a layman, it would seem that the numbers generated could be easily reproduced through brute force if using, for example, an integer between 1 and 100 as the seed. I have seen 0 and 1 used quite often. Even with time as a random see, it might be brute forced if the starting time could be closely monitored. But brute forcing a random 256 bit number would be pretty tough.

Am I correct or is there some mechanism unknown to me that makes this a non-issue?

I will not even pretend to be more than a end-user of others work in this area and understand that my question may be naive. Yet it is something I do not understand and would appreciate some help.

I am currently working on a project in python 3.x (which is also pretty new to me) so tagged the question with that string but the question is really more generic than a particular languages implementation (I think).

Comment: Pseudorandom number generators can be used in technical and scientific applications, for example, games or simulations, or in cryptographic applications. For the first use case, the size of the seed doesn't count very much. (That's because in technical and scientific applications we are more interested in the statistical properties of a sequence of numbers than in making the numbers hard to predict.) For the second use case, you want to seed the generator with a random seed with as many bits as the generator's internal state, and you must get the seed from a cryptographically secure source.

Comment: So am I understanding correctly that the greater the bits of the of the seed the more difficult for someone to 'guess' the starting seed and thus be able to reproduce your randomization scheme but that you should not ever use it for that purpose. Instead, use a a 'real' random source for cryptographicallly secure prng's that may need a seed? Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: You don't have to use a real random source. All you need is a cryptographically secure source, such as a value obtained from a trusted CPRNG, for example `/dev/urandom`.

Comment: I understand that using a source such as urandom is good advice for getting a random seed. However, if by pure chance, urandom returned a value of 1, would an adversary that also used the value 1 as a seed have the exact same string of numbers returned by the csprng? OR, is the nature of a csprng such that the passage of time, for example, would cause different values to be returned? It is my understanding that the first case would be true. Am I correct in this belief??

Comment: Most real encryption system have a step where they look at the quality of the proposed key and discard it if it does not fit a set of criteria. No serious encryption system would accept a key with low apparent entropy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of the seed is important at least in the sense that it is ideally equal to the state length of the PRNG. Although seeds that have been used in common practice are 32 or 64 bits long, such seeds are generally appropriate only if the underlying PRNG's state length is 32 or 64 bits, respectively. Many modern PRNGs have longer state lengths, though. (In general, the greater the variety of seeds, the greater the variety of random number sequences a PRNG can generate.)

Comment: I'd like to see some justification for the "should". It does look natural, yeah. However, a Mersenne Twister has plenty of properties which make it "better" than a linear congruential generator, even if they are both seeded with a 32-bit value, which is often the case. Still, both are not cryptographically secure in any way if that is the main concern.

Comment: My statement is independent of the nature of the PRNG; it applies equally to cryptographic and noncryptographic PRNGs (of course, noncryptographic PRNGs are inappropriate whenever information security is involved).  In any case, Mersenne Twister has a much bigger state than most linear congruential generators seen in applications, which have 32-bit or smaller moduli (and therefore a state length of 32 bits or less).

Answer (score 1):

The seed is only important from a *predictability* perspective. This seed has no impact on how "random" the numbers are that come out of the PRNG after it's seeded.

If you need your numbers to be unpredictable, as in *if* someone could figure out your seed and generate the same sequence of numbers That Would Be Bad, such as if you were running a casino for real money or generating private keys for cryptography, then you cannot use tiny seeds.

You *must* use unpredictable, highly random sources of "entropy" to seed your PRNG. These are often provided by your operating system (e.g. `/dev/rand`) but many cryptographic-grade libraries also provide really good random number generator functions because of how important those functions are.

The classic `srand(time(NULL))` call, which seeds the PRNG in C with the epoch time in seconds, shows up all over the place. If you can guess what time the program was started at you can determine, precisely, what numbers come out of their generator. You can "predict" everything about that PRNG. Since there's only ~2.1 billion possible times, you could even brute-force this. If you know +/- a few hours it's only a few thousand possibilities to try, making it even more trivial.

Remember the "P" in PRNG stands for "pseudo" which means "fake". The numbers look random but are procedurally generated and the only way you can prevent people from discovering what those numbers are is by seeding your PRNG properly.

Comment: `the only way you can prevent people from discovering what those numbers are is by seeding your PRNG properly.` this is nonsense

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux: Can you be more specific?